# p-variation of x

Tags: calculus, inequality, normed-spaces

Let us consider data $(k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}, (s_1, \ldots, s_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k_{\ge 0})$ such that $s_1 + \ldots + s_k = 1$. The *mesh* of a datum like that is $\max (s_1, \ldots, s_k)$. Given $p > 1$, what is a nice way to see that, as the mesh tends to zero, $s_1^p + \ldots + s_k^p$ tends to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do
$$
\sum s_i^p = \sum s_i s_i^{p-1} \leq (\max \{ s_i \} )^{p-1} \sum s_i = {\text{mesh}}^{p-1}
$$